# Error with r-base in conda enviroments for Windows

Tags: r, anaconda, environment-variables, conda, conda-forge

I want to create an R environment with conda, using environment files .yml, over Win64x. Specifically, I'm using the next YAML file:

```
name: habits_env
channels:
  - r
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - r-base
  - jupyter
  - jupyterlab
  - r-irkernel
  - r-ggpubr
  - r-broom
  - r-caret
  - r-catools
  - r-devtools
  - r-ggwordcloud
  - r-glmnet
  - r-gridextra
  - r-liblinear
  - r-magrittr
  - r-plotroc
  - r-r6
  - r-randomforest
  - r-rocr
  - r-rodbc
  - r-rweka
  - r-stringr
  - r-tidytext
  - r-tidyverse
  - r-tm
```

The packages and dependencies are installed without problems, but when I run R, the next problem happens (this problem persists even if I install only r-base):

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'grDevices' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'D:/Usuarios/daimmuos/Anaconda3/envs/ensayo/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/x64/grDevices.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  No se encontr¾ el proceso especificado.

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'graphics' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'D:/Usuarios/daimmuos/Anaconda3/envs/ensayo/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/x64/grDevices.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  No se encontr¾ el proceso especificado.

Error: package or namespace load failed for 'stats' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'D:/Usuarios/daimmuos/Anaconda3/envs/ensayo/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/x64/grDevices.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  No se encontr¾ el proceso especificado.

Durante la inicializaci¾n - Warning messages:
1: package 'grDevices' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
2: package 'graphics' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
3: package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
```

If a use *mro-base* instead of *r-base*, R executes properly, but I have a lot of conflicts between the packages and the enviroment ends by not creating.

I am using *r-base=3.6.1* from *r* channel.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Please include the steps you use to start an R session. It could be a channel-incompatibility issue (`r/defaults` and `conda-forge` use different build stacks). What happens if you try it without the `conda-forge` channel included?

Comment: Thanks @merv for answering me. I use the next steps to start an R session, after the environment is created:
`conda activate habits_env`
`R`

The results are the same when I exclude `conda-forge` from the selected channels.